# Getting runtime error for having an array present even though it is not flagged for persistence

Tags: swift, realm

I wanted to create a list var on my Realm object class that would *not* persist. However, I am still receiving a runtime error even though this var is not pre-fixed with dynamic.

Is this intended? Why would Realm still care even when its not persisting?

```
class Test: Object {
    var test = []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is intended. The `dynamic` keyword is required for the standard property types, but Lists are structured differently, and do not normally require it.

To absolutely, explicitly set your object as non-persisted, you just need to override `Object`'s `ignoredProperties` method and specify the property in there:

```
override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["test"]
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks you! Was not aware of this, but your suggested solution works perfectly for me.